# #define preprocessor in c#

Tags: c#, console, c-preprocessor

I am coming from a C++ background, trying to learn C#.

I find it really annoying, that every time I wish to print something to the console I have to type something like `Console.WriteLine("whatever");`

If I was using C++ I would just define something like `print(x)` with a `#define`, but in C# I can't get it working.

My code is like this:

```
#define print(x) Console.WriteLine(x);
```

The issue is that C# wants me to keep it at the top of my code, before I have included my "`using system`" headers. Thus, the compiler does not know what `Console` or `WriteLine()` are. If I put it below this, I get an error telling me I need to have my preprocessor at the top.

Can someone help me out and tell me how I could get around this issue.

Comment: Look at [code snippets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx), not same, but usefull.

Comment: Time to get used to writing 2 words instead of 1. I know, it's a huge sacrifice.

Answer (score 4):

No such luck as preprocessor macros to abbreviate, but in C#6 you can use *using static* to make the calls slightly less verbose;

```cs
using static System.Console;

namespace TestConsole
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            WriteLine ("Test");    // Uses Console.WriteLine
        } 
    }
}
```

...and - of course - you can use it to get your print function;

```cs
using static Utility;

static class Utility {
    public static void print(string format, params object[] parms) {
        System.Console.WriteLine (format, parms);
    }
}

namespace TestConsole
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            print ("Test {0}", "this");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`#define` in **C**# is used only to defines symbols, which can be used in `#if` directives.

From **MSDN**:

> The #define directive cannot be used to declare constant values as is typically done in C and C++. Constants in C# are best defined as static members of a class or struct. If you have several such constants, consider creating a separate "Constants" class to hold them.
>
> Symbols can be used to specify conditions for compilation. You can test for the symbol with either #if or #elif. You can also use the conditional attribute to perform conditional compilation.
>
> You can define a symbol, but you cannot assign a value to a symbol. The #define directive must appear in the file before you use any instructions that aren't also preprocessor directives.

There is a snippet you can use:

type **cw** and press *TAB* + *TAB*